# Is this natural gas shut off valve behaving correctly?

Tags: valve, natural-gas

The natural gas shut off valve in the picture below is installed behind my oven. Usually when I see a valve like this, if I turn it 90 degrees, it will turn until it stops. When it stops 90 degrees from where it started, the valve is off.

However, with this valve, it doesn't stop at 90 degrees. It continues turning 180 degrees until it's facing the other direction. The valve is on in both of those positions. If I stop turning the valve at 90 degrees, it does appear to shut off, but like I said, nothing stop me from continuing to turn the valve to 180 degrees.

Is the valve meant to function this way or was something installed incorrectly? It seems strange to me to not have the valve stop at 90 degrees so you know it is definitely off. The way it is now you are basically guessing that you have properly turned the valve 90 degrees to shut the gas off.

[image]

Is this right?

Comment: Just to clarify - you're saying in your last paragraph that in the position shown in your photo, the valve is off, and from this position a 90 degree turn in either direction turns the valve on?

Comment: No @brhans in the photo, the valve is on. When you turn it 90 degrees, the valve is off, however, it doesn't stop turning, it continues to turn all the way to 180 degrees, where it turns back on.

Comment: is the handle loose? ... did someone put a washer under the handle and now it is sitting too high? ... i see an endstop just above the logo on the side of the valve body ... the handle appears to be touching it, but the picture is unclear ... the endstop should prevent clockwise rotation of the handle ... have a closer look at the valve handle position

Comment: the nut on top appears to be upside down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the red lever is in line with the pipe then the valve is open. When the red lever is across or at 90 degrees to the pipe it is shut. This is a very simple visual system.

I think the red lever has lost the pin or protruding part that would act as the stop for normal operation. For your safety, and others, it would be a good idea to get it replaced - if just the lever needs replacing then that is easy. But if the complete assembly needs replacing then in some places you will need a qualified gas fitter.

Comment: Right, but normally you know it's definitely shut because the lever stops turning at 90 degrees. For some reason this one keeps turning all the way to 180.

Comment: @flyingL123 that is what I address in the second short paragraph...

Comment: Gotcha thanks. So is this a safety concern at all? Should I have the valve replaced?

Comment: @flyingL123 see edit.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way for me to know if it's the lever or the entire assembly that needs replacing? It's a brand new installation which is why I find this extremely frustrating.

Comment: A brand new installation, then get them back...

Comment: Also, when someone tells me it's a "180 degree" valve that was installed for convenience, that's probably BS right?

Comment: If you zoom in on the picture you can see part of the red lever has broken off. It looks like the "stop" pin  is still on the valve so you could probably just get a new valve and just replace the lever